# Spyne: How to decode POST into JSON using HttpRpc

Tags: json, rest, spyne

I am trying to build a REST application using sypne. I want to receive a JSON document (but not with with the method called as the name of the object. I give en example to clarify:
I make a POST to the URL `http://localhost/root` with the following content:

```
{ "id": 1, "desc": "number" }
```

And I have my spyne application:

```
class HelloWorldService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(_returns=AnyDict)
    def root(ctx):
        json_in=""
        for data in ctx.in_string:
            json_in = json_in + data
        return json.loads(json_in)

application = Application([HelloWorldService],
          tns='com.hello.webservices',
          in_protocol=HttpRpc(validator='soft'),
          out_protocol=JsonDocument()
      )
```

And I *know* there has to be a better way of doing this! Any pointers to documentation or solution appreciated in advance!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spyne doesn't have that functionality ouf the box, you need to implement your own protocol for that.

It's pretty easy though. Off the top of my head:

```
class HybridHttpJsonDocument(JsonDocument):
    def create_in_document(self, ctx):
        super(HybridHttpJsonDocument, self).create_in_document(ctx)

        # get url fragment from ctx.transport.req_env

        ctx.in_document = {url_fragment: ctx.in_document}
```

That's all I can think of that you need to do. Please report back with your results!

Best regards,

Comment: If you have further questions, please join people@spyne.io and fire away :)

Comment: Hello and thanks. And I should use this new class as in_protocol, right? Will this let me handle headers and HTTP result codes? - Regards.

Comment: Yes, this is your new input protocol.

Comment: About headers: They are also accessible from `ctx.transport.req_env`. But if you want to deserialize them to Python classes as well, you need to define an in_header class in @rpc and populate ctx.in_header_doc from `ctx.transport.req_env`

Comment: About HTTP response code: You can set it via `ctx.transport.resp_code`. The HTTP response codes are at `spyne.const.http`